# PHPUnit Path problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, include-path

I am writing a ZF application.  I had some abstract parent classes in a library directory.  Netbeans could generate test skeletons for the child classes no problems, and I could run the tests no problem.

Later on I decided to move the abstract parents out of the library and in to the application directory (to improve readability).  I updated my application code accordingly, and it runs no problem.

However, now when I use netbeans to generate test skeletons for the child classes, it gives a fatal error saying it can not find the parent.  I then constructed a test class manually and ran it from the command line, and PHPUnit gave the same error.

What do I need to do to get this pathing working correctly?  In the PHPUnit bootstrap I tried adding the Application directory to the include path, and registering Application as a namespace with the Zend Autoloader.  I don't think this is a recommended practice, and it failed anyhow...

I really do struggle with path issues, finding files, etc...

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I can move the classes from the library to the core code directories, and the core code finds them no problems because they conform to the standard naming conventions autoladed by ZF.

Other applications (e.g. PHPUnit) won't be able to find them though.  I could get around this by setting their autoloading the same ZF.  Alternatively, I could incorporate required files with require_once (which would negate the use of autoloading in the first place).

So, it seems that my best shot is to put the shared classes back in the library.  My original PHPUnit bootstrap adds the library prefix to the ZF autoloader, so I'm good to go.

All-in-all, I've just learned another good use for libraries.

[EDIT:] Another Alternative...

My test classes are boostrapping Zend Application which sets up the autoloading for PHPUnit.  The only drawback doing it this way is that PHPUnit (via my netbeans IDE) can't create the skeleton tests for me.  I guess I'll have to live with that.